# 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Am trying to choose random photos from an array and then add them to the stage buy I have this error in the last line :
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

```
Photos = new Array();

        photo2 = new img2();
        photo3 = new img3();
        photo4 = new img4();
        //put those images into an array
        Photos.push(photo2);            
        Photos.push(photo3);
        Photos.push(photo4);

function getRandomElementOf(Photos:Array):Object {
            var idx:int=Math.floor(Math.random() * Photos.length);
            trace(idx);
            return Photos[idx];
        }

    public function addPhoto(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace("clicked compass");


        **stage.addChild(getRandomElementOf(Photos));**
```

Hope to get your feedback soon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an object to stage , in your case what you get is an object and you cannot add them to stage , to add a image load that image to `<s:Image source=""/>` and then add this image component to stage!

Comment: I have all of my images in the library

Answer (score 0):

Make your function return a DisplayObject:

```
function getRandomElementOf(Photos:Array):DisplayObject 
{
    var idx:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * Photos.length);            
    return DisplayObject(Photos[idx]);
}
```

or cast:

```
stage.addChild(DisplayObject(getRandomElementOf(Photos)));
```